# Duplication with CascadeType

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm a little bit confused right now. I have three tables: specialPrice, partner, product.

In the specialPrice I can store discount for products which will available for the selected partner. So it has only three columns. Partner and product table and they row is referenced from the specialPrice table.

These three tables are represented as entities in my Java application as well. Here is my problem: if I want to store one specialPrice I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: 0.
```

the error message is helpful, I have to use CascadeType, okay. BUT if I use the CascadeType.ALL the specialPrice will be created (so no more java.lang.IllegalStateException), but in the product and in the partner table the selected partner and the product will be duplicated... I don't understand how is this possible?

specialPrice Entity:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "DISCOUNT_RATE")
private int discountRate;

@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Product productId;

@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Partner partnerId;
```

reference from partner Entity:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "partnerId")
private Collection<SpecialPrice> specialPriceCollection;
```

(same for the product)

Using EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)

Can someone help me, what am I doing wrong? I don't want to duplicate the selected partner and product...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand `Partner` and `Product` are both pre-existing entities?

In such case, try the following code in your service method:

```
specialPrice.setPartner(partnerRepository.getOne(specialPrice.getPartnerId().getId());
specialPrice.setProduct(productRepository.getOne(specialPrice.getProductId().getId());
specialPriceRepository.save(specialPrice);
```

As a side note, using `CascadeType.ALL` with `@ManyToOne` is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Yes, they pre-existing. One question: how do I prevent the exception, because what you suggested is not Entity related and right now there is something not okay in the Entity without the CascadeType. Some "relationship" is creating a "new object" what i don't want. What should I remove?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean... I will have a look into this, thx :)